# Crystal Report that unites the contents of four separate forms

Tags: forms, crystal-reports, report

I have four separate forms being completed over a roughly 72 hour period. I need to run a single report that unites the contents of these four separate forms (with different tables) into one master report.   Now, it MAY be that we can simply pull in by the episode number.  But that may not be true.  The first form in the series of four is typically done prior to admission and may reside in a separate episode.  Assuming it is in a different episode, how best do I unite the four forms into one report.  Before you answer, a further complication:  These forms are repeated annually and these would be against the same episode as the original admissions were done (at least 3 out of the four).  So, I need to be careful to not include multiple records that were given a year apart into the same master report output.

Here’s what the records might look like after a couple of years:

```
Record #    Episode #   Date    Form
1   1   5/01/2012   Form     A
2   2   5/01/2012   Form     B
3   2   5/01/2012   Form     C
4   2   5/02/2012   Form     D
5   2   4/25/2013   Form     B
6   2   4/27/2013   Form     C
7   2   4/29/2013   Form     D
8   2   4/12/2014   Form     B
9   2   4/16/2014   Form     D
```

So, records 1-4 should be combined into one master report.  But say I run the report on 6/1/2013.   I would want to specify if I wanted the original admission report (records 1-4) or the annual update (records 5-7)  Note, Form A is only ever done at admission.     Of course, come 5/1/2014, I might want the admission or either of the two subsequent annual reviews, noting that the second annual review is missing a form.

I know it is messy.  What’s the best way to handle this?

The safest but most manually intensive way I can think of is to present the user running the report with four drop down fields that return the existing forms and have the user manually pick the ones they want to combine.  I’m a bit worried about user error, though….  Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you clarify the business rules a bit more?  I don't understand which form should be displayed when.  Moreover, do each of these forms have different fields?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is one main report that contains four sub-reports (A-D), linked together by the patient's ID.  You can hide/show each sub-report as desired.

If the main report contains the patient's admission information, then you can use it to drive some of the logic.

If you want more help, you need to articulate the rules more concisely.